# Need the output of one php file to other php file

Tags: php

I want to grab the output of one php file to other, I am passing arguments to php file and the return value is 1 , I want to store the value in other php.

I am running this from shell as -

```
php t.php nicholashodges@juno.com
```

Now I want to run this from a php file which will grab the output of this into variable in the other php?

Comment: If the output of the code 1 is printed or echoed, you can use phps output buffers to capture the output content as a variable. http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 1):

From the second script

```
$out = exec("php t.php nicholashodges@juno.com");
```

Or

```
exec("php t.php nicholashodges@juno.com", $out);
```

Or maybe from shell

```
php t.php nicholashodges@juno.com > second.php
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help you :)